# Database error in core/Loader.php -- postgresql + codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, php-pgsql

i am getting the following error :

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346
```

my database.php is :

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'usertest';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'usertest';
$db['default']['port']     = '5433';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'postgre';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

What is the possible solution. I do not want to $db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
as even after doing this i am still not able to connect to db.

EDIT :
Changed the port to 5432. still it doesnt work

Comment: Are you sure postgres is on port 5433?  try `telnet localhost 5433` from command line and see if you get a blank screen.

Comment: Same question, Posgres's default port is 5432.

Comment: "postgre"?  I think you're missing an s

Answer (score 0):

Set `Set $db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;` and check once again.

Answer (score 0):

> Some database drivers (such as PDO, PostgreSQL, Oracle, ODBC) might
>   require a full DSN string to be provided. If that is the case, you
>   should use the ‘dsn’ configuration setting, as if you’re using the
>   driver’s underlying native PHP extension, like this:

```
$db['default']['dsn'] = 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=database_name';
```

[from official documentation of codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your db driver name. I am pretty sure it is "postgres" and not "postgre."